# Математические операции SELECT

Tags: sql

Есть две таблицы:

```
Tab1:
ID  Name    
1   Иванов  
2   Петров  
3   Сидоров

Tab2:
TransID|RcvID|SndID|Quantity
1       1     2      1000
2       1     3      1500
3       3     1      3000
4       2     1      500
```

Где,
TransID – просто ид операции

RcvID – ид получателя (из 1й табл)

SndID – ид отправителя (из 1й табл)

Quantity – количество передаваемых денег

Мне нужно посчитать суммарное число денег, образовавшееся на Иванове, Петрове, сидорове, в результате проведенных операций.

Я отталкивался от логики, что сначала нужно посчитать сколько денег потерял каждый и сгрупировать сколько будет у них в итоге денег по SndID - это будут отрициательные значения, а потом к этим значениям уже прибавлять сколько они получили RcvID, так мы может получить итоговое кол-во денег для Иванова, Петрова, Сидорова.

У меня получилось посчитать сколько всего они потеряли каждый. Но Как мне оперировать этими значениями что бы к ним прибавить по RcvID

```
SELECT
c.ID, MAX(c.Name) as Name,  SUM((0-ts.Quantity)) AS Summa
FROM tab1 c
LEFT JOIN  tab2 ts on ts.SndID = c.ID
GROUP BY c.ID
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select name, sum(q) from tab1
join
(select rcvid id, quantity q from tab2
union all
select sndvid, -quantity from tab2) x
on tab1.id= x.id
group by x.id, name
```

Answer (score 0):

По сути вы можете заставить создать временно нужные таблицы в базе, и использовать их. Хотя такие вещи обычно просто делаются через обновление при выполнении записи. Но вот решение вашей задачи.

```
SELECT *,   SUM(recive_money-send_money) AS result
FROM tableone c
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT rcvid, SUM(quantity) AS recive_money FROM tabletwo GROUP BY rcvid ) AS recive ON recive.rcvid = c.id
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT sndid, SUM(quantity) AS send_money FROM tabletwo GROUP BY sndid ) AS send ON send.sndid = c.id
GROUP BY c.ID
```